# Связь Android-приложения и MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, веб-служба

Немного погуглив, решил связать через php. До этого с php не работал никогда.
Связь налажена, смущает только то что соединение с базой (я делал точно как в примере) идет через connect.php, который содержит логин и пароль к ДБ. Меня волнует вопрос безопасности: то что можно изменять и пополнять базу, минуя само приложение. Нужно только знать названия скриптов и адрес сервера. Быть может, есть смысл переписать скрипты так, чтобы они при каждом соединении с базой брали логин и пароль из запроса, POST или GET методом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, грамотный выход.
По задумке большой нагрузки на ДБ быть не должно, но данные которые в ней хранятся не должны попасть или быть изменены злоумышленником. Клиент достаточно серьезный и не хочется его подводить) Я бы даже рассмотрел замену php на более подходящий вариант, если в этом есть смысл. И да, я новичек, почти без опыта, так что камнями не кидайтесь)

Answer (score 3):

для таких задач существует так называемая трёх звенная архитектура: клиент - серверное приложение - база данных. На настоящее время существует несколько вариантов общения сервера (серверного приложения) с клиентом. но я рекомендую остановиться на websocket -  у него есть много достоинств, но одно следует выделить - по данному протоколу могут работать и браузеры и приложения. я рекомендую произвети замену php на java (тем более что на андроиде как правило на (почти) java пишут), для секретности ws заменить на wss. ws/wss экономит трафик, нагрузку на сервер, ... в общем моя практика показывает только плюсы.
ЗЫ
по твоему варианту - http://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/256665/

Answer (score 2):

Работая через определенное API, ты ограничиваешь возможности по изменению БД рамками этого API.
Сохраняя в приложении пароль к БД, ты даешь полный доступ к базе вообще всем.

Поэтому-то с mysql никто никогда Андроид не связывает. Любое приложение должно быть связано с серверным API. Которому посылается не готовый запрос, а определенная команда и данные. Точно так же, как это делается на веб-сайтах: браузер не связан с БД. Он делает запрос к сайту, а сайт уже формирует SQL для БД.

Точно так же должно работать и твое приложение. При этом, разумеется, делая все нужные проверки (авторизацию, проверку прав и так далее).

А бояться доступа и изменения данных не нужно.
Скажем, адреса серверов Stack Overflow, или там Yandex Почты известны всем. Имена скриптов посмотреть тоже нетрудно. Задавая вопрос или отправляя письмо, ты несомненно меняешь данные в БД. Кого-то это пугает?

Answer (score 0):

Ты открываешь полный доступ к базе данных. Так приложения не пишутся. Я так понимаю сервер в интернете? Имеет смысл перенести php скрипты на тот же сервер, а из приложения посылать к ним запросы.

К примеру, я пишу мессенджер под андроид. Он посылает данные в формате json на сервер с php, а уже php работает с MySQL.